# Extend AC hose and install an additional fan

Tags: hvac

I have an AC in my dorm which works great. During summer I connect the AC via a fitting to the window to cool the room. Due to restructuring of my chamber I want to move the AC in one of the corners of my room. However the hose is not long enough and I suspect the power of the integrated fan is not either.

Can I install an additional fan which sucks air "through" the AC? Intuitively I would say the additional fan has to be as large as such that the volume flow is the same as if the AC is placed directly near the window?
Is this consideration correct?
And how is it best realized?

Comment: A duct booster fan?

Comment: @Kris Yes exactly..Should the booster fan be as strong as such that the volume flow is the same as when the AC is placed near the window as it is supposed to be or can it be stronger?

Comment: Is it a 4 or 6” hose? Any idea how much air flow is going through this hose now? I think diminishing the flow would be bad but increasing by a little may be beneficial.

Comment: Its about 6inch..I could not find any specifications regarding airflow..However it feels rather weak.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Inline-Fan-Built-Controller-Pre-Wired/dp/B06X3VDXVF.  I’d give it a try with a variable speed unit. Check temperature of exhaust before adding the extra length and booster. Then operate fan at a speed that matches or is less than that temp.  I suppose there is no option for venting through a wall or floor opening available?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other opening than the window...I like the idea with the variable speed unit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is not any option to vent without extending the length of the vent hose I would try using a [variable speed duct booster fan.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06X3VDXVF)
[image]

You want to be sure you are not restricting the flow of warm air at all. 
To help ensure this check the temperature of the vented air on a hot day before adding any length.
Then add your extension and booster.

Adjust the speed until the temperature of the exiting air is  the same or a bit cooler than original temp. 
Running faster speed than this may cause premature failure of the integrated fan so be careful.

If your unit runs continuously this set up may be fine. If it cycles on and off you will need to think about how to get the booster fan to cycle with it.